# GraalVM installation fails on macOS Big Sur (Apple m1)

Tags: java, macos, graalvm, apple-m1

I followed the steps found here: https://www.graalvm.org/docs/getting-started/macos/ to install GraalVM on macOS Big Sur, but when I try run `java -version` I get the following error:

[image]

Is there a way to use GraalVM on Apple M1 or is it not supported yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the pop-up wasn't that accurate, it seems that there's a problem with signing GraalVM (something about untrusted developers)

solved with:

```
sudo xattr -r -d com.apple.quarantine /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/<path-to-graalvm>
```